# Game Audio Production Pipeline 

Tags: gameaudio

I'm curious as to what the audio production workflow looks like at in-house game studios working on large scale projects.

Can anyone give me any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this thread:
[Game Audio Culture](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/10422/game-audio-culture)

Comment: This is perfect thanks! I've been working for small out of house audio company for some time now and the idea of working in-house sounds very attractive to me.